# Zeller's algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have implemented [Zeller's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) in Python to calculate the day of the week for some given date. I would like to get some feedback on how I can make the code shorter and more elegant:

```
def input_value(input_name, prompt, min_num, max_num):
    while True:
        data = raw_input(prompt)
        if data:
            try:
                input_name = int(data)
            except ValueError:
                print 'Invalid input...'
            else:
                if input_name >= min_num and input_name <= max_num:
                    return input_name
                    break
                input_name = 'Please try again: '
        else:
            print 'Goodbye!'
            break


month = 0
day = 0
year = 0
century = 0

month = input_value(month, "Please enter the month (from 1-12, where March is 1 and February is 12): ", 1, 12)
day = input_value(day, "Please enter the day (from 1-31): ", 1, 31)
year = input_value(year, "Please enter the year (from 0 - 99, eg. 88 in 1988): ", 0, 99)
century = input_value(century, "Please enter the century (from 0 - 99, eg. 19 in 1988): ", 0, 99)

A = month
B = day
C = year
D = century

W = (13*A - 1) / 5
X = C / 4
Y = D / 4
Z = W + X + Y + B + C - 2*D
R = Z % 7

birthday = "You were born on " + str(B) + "/" + str(A+2) + "/" + str(D) + str(C) + " which was a "

if R == 0:
    print birthday + 'Sunday'
elif R == 1:
    print birthday + 'Monday'
elif R == 2:
    print birthday + 'Tuesday'
elif R == 3:
    print birthday + 'Wednesday'
elif R == 4:
    print birthday + 'Thursday'
elif R == 5:
    print birthday + 'Friday'
elif R == 6:
    print birthday + 'Saturday'
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def input_value(input_name, prompt, min_num, max_num):
```

`input_name` is always a number - why are you calling it a 'name'? Also, there's no need to take it as an argument, since you never use its initial value in your function.

```
    while True:
        data = raw_input(prompt)
        if data:
            try:
                input_name = int(data)
            except ValueError:
                print 'Invalid input...'
```

Consider putting a `continue` here, for clarity. It isn't necessary, though.

```
            else:
                if input_name >= min_num and input_name <= max_num:
```

Python understands `if min_num <= input_name <= max_num:`

```
                    return input_name
                    break
```

You don't need `break` here, the `return` makes it unreachable.

```
                input_name = 'Please try again: '
```

Assigning a string to something that's otherwise always a number is odd, and this value is never used anyway. Nix this line.

```
        else:
            print 'Goodbye!'
            break
```

This will end up falling off the end of the function, and so returning `None`. The rest of your script will continue, but eventually fail horribly. This probably isn't what you want.

```
month = 0
day = 0
year = 0
century = 0
```

Only reason to initialise these to 0 is to pass them into `input_value`, but, as I said above, it never uses the zero values. So, you don't need this.

```
month = input_value(month, "Please enter the month (from 1-12, where March is 1 and February is 12): ", 1, 12)
```

March = 1 is an odd system. Consider inputting it as January=1 and then transforming it with:

```
# Weirdify month counting
month = month - 2 if month < 3 else month + 10
```

To not surprise your users.

```
day = input_value(day, "Please enter the day (from 1-31): ", 1, 31)
year = input_value(year, "Please enter the year (from 0 - 99, eg. 88 in 1988): ", 0, 99)
century = input_value(century, "Please enter the century (from 0 - 99, eg. 19 in 1988): ", 0, 99)
```

These lines are very long. You should wrap them per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

```
 year = input_value("Please enter the century (from 0 - 99, eg. 19 in 1988): ",
                     0, 99)
```

Also, you might consider inputting `year` and `century` as a single value ('1988') and separating it in the script.

```
A = month
B = day
C = year
D = century
```

Just use the long names throughout your formulae, eg `X = year / 4`.

```
W = (13*A - 1) / 5
X = C / 4
Y = D / 4
Z = W + X + Y + B + C - 2*D
R = Z % 7

birthday = "You were born on " + str(B) + "/" + str(A+2) + "/" + str(D) + str(C) + " which was a "
```

Use string formatting instead of concatenation:
    birthday = "You were born on {}/{}/{}, which was a {}{}".format(day, month+2, 
                                                                    century, year)

```
if R == 0:
    print birthday + 'Sunday'
elif R == 1:
    print birthday + 'Monday'
elif R == 2:
    print birthday + 'Tuesday'
elif R == 3:
    print birthday + 'Wednesday'
elif R == 4:
    print birthday + 'Thursday'
elif R == 5:
    print birthday + 'Friday'
elif R == 6:
    print birthday + 'Saturday'
```

This can go into a list:

```
 days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
         'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
 day_of_week = days[R]
```

And then that can go in the above string formatting instead of being concatenated on later.

Comment: @Ivc thanks, this is really great advice. There are two points which I don't fully understand. I don't know how to use `continue`, even after looking it up on the python docs. I also don't fully understand the 'string formatting' and 'listing days of the week' point. Can you offer any more advice here?

Comment: `continue` is sortof like `break`, except that it goes back to the top of the loop instead of falling out the bottom. For string formatting, look up the documentation for `str.format()`, and the "String Formatting mini language". Basically it achieves the same thing as concatenating all your variables into the string, except its easier to read, and potentially more efficient (especially if your code ever gets run on, say, PyPy). For the days of the week, `days[0]` is `'Sunday'` - it avoids the chain of `if`/`elif`, and will error instead of failing silently if your R is >6 somehow.